# Html agility pack failed to scrape image

Tags: vb.net, image, html-agility-pack, scrape

Ok I have found a code which as the website declared scrape `image` from `div` using htmlagility pack vb.net.

I followed the procedure and I get nothing.
This is source html:

```
<div class='my-gallery'>

                    <!-- ONLY PREV NAVIGATION -->
                                        <!-- ONLY PREV NAVIGATION -->

                    <img src='http://example.com/image.jpg' alt='image'/>

                    <!-- ONLY NEXT NAVIGATION -->
                                        <!-- ONLY NEXT NAVIGATION -->

</div>
```

This is vb.net code I tried:

```
Public Sub getImg()


        Try
            Dim link As String = ("http://www.exmple.com")
            'download page from the link into an HtmlDocument'
            Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(link)
            Dim div As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='my-gallery']//img//src")
            If Not div Is Nothing Then              
               PreviewBox.ImageLocation = (div.ToString)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Anyone? hmmm.. thats weird

Comment: Isn't the `<img>` the node and `src` an *attribute* of that node?

Comment: I'm just learning I can't answer you correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `src` is an attribute of the `img` element, so you need to extract it slightly differently, for example:

```
Dim img As HtmlNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='my-gallery']//img")
If img IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim url As String = img.Attributes("src").Value
    PreviewBox.ImageLocation = url
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew for taking your time to help me out ,appreciate.